# Disable DAC Pins on Pin 25 and 26 on ESP32 Module

Tags: esp32

I have made a custom board and everything is working perfectly. However, there are two pins GPIO25 and GPIO26 which are connected to external interrupts. They are not working. Later I removed all connections and found that these two pins are DAC pins and by default they output ~2v. I am using Arduino environment.

Can someone please suggest how to disable DAC and convert them to GPIO? Below is a simple blink LED sketch. However, the output on the pins is always 1.9v whether the pin status is set to high or low.

```
#define PIN1 26
#define PIN2 25

// the setup function runs once when you press reset or power the board
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(PIN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PIN2, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(PIN1, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  digitalWrite(PIN2, LOW);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(3000);                       // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(PIN1, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  digitalWrite(PIN2, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(3000);                       // wait for a second
}
```

Comment: Which MCU would that be? There's dozens of platforms with Arduino support, so specific platform name is required for a specific answer.

Comment: that was my mistake. I am using ESP32 4MB module